# What is the difference between jms 1.1 and 2.0 and are they backwards compatible with older drivers?

Tags: java, jms, tibco

I use a tibco driver under the jms hood to create client connections to an ems broker... I thought about upgrading the driver to latest and greatest, before I start just wondering if javax.jms package is backwards compatible and what does the version difference entail? Example: old tibco driver is packaged with (what I assume to be as it's not clearly specified anywhere) javax.jms 1.1 (built in April 2002) however the new driver is bundled with jms 2.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JMS2.0 is backard compatible with JMS1.1. You can still consume or produce messages using javax.jms 1.1 legacy API if you want with a JMS2.0 implementation.

See also

- https://www.infoq.com/news/2013/06/JMS_2.0_Released
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jms20-1947669.html